# Adding date-check functionality to CMS Static Block

Tags: cms, cms-block

I want to add the ability to do a date check inside a CMS Static Block. Something like this:

```
{{if date == '2015-12-25'}}Merry Christmas!{{else}}It's not Christmas{{/if}}
```

However, I'm not sure how to introduce new functionality like this. I haven't been successful even using `{{if}}` statements like this with existing variables.

Some pointers on getting `{{if}}` statements working, and adding custom variables which can be accessed this way should be enough. I can populate said variable with the date pretty easily.

Answer (score 2):

you can create block and `phtml` file and can call that in CMS page. In phtml file you can add `IF-ELSE statement`.

Here is example to display newsletter block in CMS page:

Place below code where you want to display **NEWS LETTER** box.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('newsletter/subscribe')->setTemplate('newsletter/subscribe.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Call in CMS page:

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

**Note:** You can create simple block and phml file like `subscribe.phtml` and add condition to that file:

```
 {{if date == '2015-12-25'}}Merry Christmas!{{else}}It's not Christmas{{/if}}
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: The problem is that while I, the developer, am perfectly comfortable working with a phtml file, the content entry staff can't be mucking with phtml files in Git and pushing changes across multiple servers. I'm looking for a way to enable them to do this logic themselves in the CMS.

Comment: Then edit the adminhtml and add time input boxes and code a logic so that the static block does not show if it is not in the time which you have specified. And it should always show if no date is entered at all. You will have to extend the cms static block model to add your time attributes.